# Creating xsd from xml

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a .xsd file , in which I have one element which have few other child elements. Also, there is one .xml file which contains testcases and testresults.
My task is to create another .xsd file using this .xml file and inherit the extra elements, if needed.

But I guess there is some namespace issue due to which my testcase is failing. Also, elements are not getting inherited, although I used extension base for the same. Schema file is:

```
<xs:complexType name="PopButtonType">
 <xs:sequence name="InLine" type="InLineType">
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="InlineType">
<xs:choice>
  xs:element name="Program" type="ProgramType"/>
 <xs:element name= "StopApp" type="StopAppType"/>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

The .xml file is as follows:

```
<testcase>
<Root>
<PopButton>
  <Inline>
    <Program context="abc"/> 
  </Inline>
</PopButton>
</Root>
</testcase>

<testresult>
<Root>
  <PopButton>
      <Inline>
          <StartApp id="xyz"/>
      </Inline>
  </PopButton>
</Root>
</testresult>
```

According to the .xml file, I need to create two .xsd file(one for testcases , another for testresults)

So, in testresults as we can see, we have one new element inside PopButton: StartApp .. please let me know how to inherit this element in another schema file.

Also, how should we do the namespacing??

Comment: Your schema is'nt valid at all e.g. on the line `<xs:sequence name="InLine" type="InLineType">`, the *name* and *type* attributes are not allowed on an `<xs:sequence>`. I guess you should correct these errors first.